# Как осуществляется подключение к серверу?

Tags: java, сервер

Подскажите пожалуйста, как осуществить подключение к серверу на языке Java, например на Battle.NET Alkar?

> war3.alkar.net - Battle.NET server
>
> 6112 - port
>
> pvpgn - bnet_cusnom_passwordhashtype

P.S.: предусмотрите вывод вспомогательных сообщений (например: `connecting to server, connected`).

Comment: Как и по локальной сети. Отличаются только адреса

Comment: Читать про класс Socket.

Comment: Чрезвычайно странный вопрос. Пример сокетного подключения приведен, но сдается мне что это не то что вы ищете. Вопрос звучит как "напишите мне пожалуйста ПО"

Answer (score 2):

Код подключения к сокету и получение сообщения.

```
try {
    Socket s = new Socket ("192.168.0.1", 8189);

    InputStream inStream = s.getInputStream();

    Scanner in = new Scanner (inStream);

    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
    }
    s.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```